# Database error after importing Wordpress

Tags: database, errors

I have moved a new website from a hosting to another (it has an older php version (5.4) so i had to export the db with the utf8_unicode_ci Charset),but now i'm having an error at www.personaltrainerbrescia.it
I noticed if I move the theme folder the error disappears, so i think it's related but i don't know how to solve it.

Thanks

Error code:

```
WordPress errore sul database Table 'Sql465609_2.wplx_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist per la query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wplx_terms AS t INNER JOIN wplx_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE t.term_id = 2 fatta da require('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-content\themes\Divi\page.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-content\themes\Divi\header.php'), wp_nav_menu, wp_get_nav_menu_object, get_term, WP_Term::get_instance
WordPress errore sul database Table 'Sql465609_2.wplx_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist per la query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wplx_terms AS t INNER JOIN wplx_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE t.slug = '2' AND tt.taxonomy = 'nav_menu' LIMIT 1 fatta da require('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-content\themes\Divi\page.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-content\themes\Divi\header.php'), wp_nav_menu, wp_get_nav_menu_object, get_term_by
WordPress errore sul database Table 'Sql465609_2.wplx_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist per la query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wplx_terms AS t INNER JOIN wplx_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE t.name = '2' AND tt.taxonomy = 'nav_menu' LIMIT 1 fatta da require('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-content\themes\Divi\page.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-content\themes\Divi\header.php'), wp_nav_menu, wp_get_nav_menu_object, get_term_by
WordPress errore sul database Table 'Sql465609_2.wplx_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist per la query SELECT  t.*, tt.* FROM wplx_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wplx_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') ORDER BY t.name ASC  fatta da require('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-content\themes\Divi\page.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-content\themes\Divi\header.php'), show_categories_menu, get_categories, get_terms, WP_Term_Query->query, WP_Term_Query->get_terms
WordPress errore sul database Table 'Sql465609_2.wplx_users' doesn't exist per la query SELECT * FROM wplx_users WHERE ID = '1' fatta da require('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('D:\inetpub\webs\personaltrainerbresciait\wp-content\themes\Divi\page.php'), the_post, WP_Query->the_post, WP_Query->setup_postdata, get_userdata, get_user_by, WP_User::get_data_by
```

Comment: Have you changed your table prefix or hardcoded any sql queries in your theme?

Comment: If you have hardcoded your table prefix, you need to find it in your theme's files. Scanning functions.php would be a great start.

Comment: Sorry guys i'm really noob in these kind of stuff.
I had to change the charset and collation of my db (utf8mb4_unicode_ci) to import it in the new hosting because it had a older php version (utf8_unicode_ci). I have to find in the theme files the charset and change it? Thanks